# How to make my page start from the top when click on a Link in React?

Tags: reactjs, scroll, onclick

Every time I click on a `<Link>` element in my React project, the Link opens a page at the middle of the screen, not at the top.

For example, I have this component

```
<Link className=" footerText" to="./about">
                  ABOUT
                </Link>
```

and when I click on in, it opens a new page/component but not at the top of the page. The user needs to scroll up in order to see the top, and I would like to open new pages directly at the top!

Comment: Please take a moment to practise using the Stack Overflow post editor when you get a moment. Both pieces of code here (an inline item of code and a block of code) were hidden because they were not correctly formatted. I have repaired them.

Answer (score 0):

React router only changes the window URL but it doesn't update the document scroll. You need to set it up when you change the page programmatically like:
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
ou may need to add something like a listener to window URL changes, to set the scroll to the very top.